# What do you call someone who is authorized to make decisions very few other people are?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example 1: A General would have the authorization to abort a military mission, a regular soldier can't.

Example 2: In a high security workplace where people use keycards for accessing rooms, John Doe can't access room 504 with his keycard, but the CEO can.

Comment: I am unaware of a single word which means both *greater authority* and *greater access.*

Comment: Yeah, I guess the examples don't add up. But, if there's a word that covers one of them, maybe I can use it.

Comment: Not a great match, but *superior* might generally cover these situations.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was playing with that word and something with *privileged*, but I can't get it right in my context.

Comment: @Clare Yep, I realized that too now.

Comment: Where I work, a school, the level of access is titled according to the position of the person who usually would require access to the computer system.  A teacher can apply for teacher's access, which might include entering grades and looking at records.  A counselor's access might include programming students for their classes and and looking at records.  The program chair access includes entering a master schedule, and the principal's level of access would include all of the above.  Superintendent's access would be like principal's, but for all the schools in the district.

Comment: Can you add an example sentence? Your examples are fine, but it's hard to pick a word without knowing how you would want to use it.

Comment: You call him "Sir".

Answer (score 1):

For your provided examples, you can use ***officer***:

> **1 b :** one charged with police duties
>
> **2 :** one who holds an office of trust, authority, or command
>    *the **officers** of the bank*
>    *chief executive **officer***
>
> **3 a :** one who holds a position of authority or command in the armed forces; *specifically* :commissioned officer
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/officer)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The people with uppermost oversight are the **Top Brass**.

> Top Brass : the people with the highest positions of authority, especially in the armed forces

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/top-brass)

> Top Brass : the people in the highest positions in an organization (such as the military or a business)

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/top%20brass)

Answer (score -1):

That is a **[Signatory](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/signatory.html)**, classically defined as any signer of a document but the contemporary and business definition is an authoritative signature who represents and decides for groups and entities.